# SQL Server database not being updated by query

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code:

```
/************************Cursors and Variables**********************/
DECLARE @id varchar(15), @type varchar(15), @new_display_order int;

--gets the areas in correct order
DECLARE @c_get_objects CURSOR
SET @c_get_objects = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT o.id 
    FROM t_object o 
    where o.type = @type 
    order by id;

/**************End cursor and variable declarations*****************/

SET @type = 'Generic'

OPEN @c_get_objects

FETCH NEXT FROM @c_get_objects
INTO @id;
SET @new_display_order = 30;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE t_object
    SET display_order = @new_display_order
    WHERE id = @id;

    SET @new_display_order = @new_display_order + 10;
END
CLOSE @c_get_objects;
DEALLOCATE @c_get_objects;
```

and when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio I get a message back saying the Command(s) completed successfully. However when I query the database it doesn't seem like the update has happened. I've double checked that the @c_get_objects gets the correct records to update and I can't see what else it could be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you put `SET @new_display_order = @new_display_order + 10;` above the prior `SET` command?

Comment: Does your query return any records to be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `@Type` before you declare your cursor, or if this is your actual query and `@Type` is hard coded to be `generic`, just put this directly in your cursor:

```
SET @c_get_objects = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT o.id 
    FROM t_object o 
    where o.type = 'Generic' 
    order by id;
```

However even if you do this your code will result in an infinte loop. You never advance the cursor inside the loop. I'd expect to see something like:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE t_object
    SET display_order = @new_display_order
    WHERE id = @id;

    SET @new_display_order = @new_display_order + 10;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @c_get_objects INTO @id;
END
```

For what it is worth though, you don't need to use a cursor at all, and it would be advisable to not.

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  o.id ,
            NewOrder = 20 + (10 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.id))
    FROM    t_object o 
    WHERE   o.type = @type 
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     display_order = NewOrder;
```

This will do the same job of incrementing `display_order` by `10` for each `ID`, but instead of using a cumbersome loop, uses the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` (starting at 30).

Answer (score 3):

You must set @Type value before on declare your cursor:

```
SET @type = 'Generic'

DECLARE @c_get_objects CURSOR
SET @c_get_objects = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT o.id 
    FROM t_object o 
    where o.type = @type 
    order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set @type before you declare the cursor...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Cursor`, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @new_display_order INT = 30

UPDATE  T
SET     T.display_order = O.new_display_order 
FROM    t_object AS T INNER JOIN  
        (SELECT ID, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) * 10) + @new_display_order AS new_display_order
         FROM   t_object) AS O ON T.ID = O.ID
WHERE   o.type = @type
```